# Log4net with azure application insights

Tags: azure, log4net, azure-application-insights

I have azure cloud service project with **web role** and integrate **log4netappender** with **application insights**. How to show the logs on **azure portal application insights**?

Comment: Its azure cloud service project with web role that why I was adding azure cloud service tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using [Application Insights Log4Net Appender](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender/),   Go to [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com), open your application and then click on **Search**.

[image]

Then, you can filter only your traces.
Clicking on a result will open a new pane on the right with more detailed information like role name, role instance, device model etc.

[image]

Comment: How it will show the details of logs because I am using logger.Info("something") for capture logs not Trace.TraceInformation("something").

Comment: Updated my answer with more details

Comment: Additionally, if you are using Visual Studio, you can go to `View -> Other Windows -> Application Insights Search` and the search window in VS will let you search for them as well.

Comment: Did i get it right, there's no way to show logger.Info, .Debug, .Error in Azure Portal even if i manage to send data via log4net appender?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Analytics where you can use the powerful Analytics query language to search, parse, extend new columns over your traces.
Just click on the Analytics button, in the same command bar which is shown above, and the Analytics portal would be opened for you.
More info can be found in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-analytics/